# How to iterate API response and make it loop through a range/list?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am developing a django-rest-framework API. My input parameters are a date and a number which represents a store's indentifier.
The API response contains some indicators related to sales for that particular store on that given date.
I want to change the API so that when only the date is passed as a parameter, the response contains indicators for all the stores.

I am querying againt a VectorWise database thus the 'state' of my SQL query.
I am looking for ways to repeat this code through loop and get a response replicated for all store numbers and not just one.

My current code is:

```
sql1 = "select num_store, sum(sales) as sales, sum(articles) as articles, sum(nb_clients) as nb_clients," \
       " sum(discount_rate) as discount_rate, sum(ind) as ind, sum(margin) as margin" \
       " from dtm.fai_vte_web_ray_jou where day = " + input_date_formatted + \
       " and num_ett = '" + store + "' GROUP BY num_ett "

sales = df1['sales'].loc[0]
articles = df1['articles'].loc[0]
nb_clients = df1['nb_clients'].loc[0]
discount = df1['discount '].loc[0]
ind = df1['ind'].loc[0]
margin = df1['margin'].loc[0]
```

There are some other calculations and then the response is created:

```
response = {
    'store': store,
    'Indicators': {
        'dailyGrossTurnover': {
            'value': sales,
            'rank': rank,
            'prog': progression_percentage},
            'dailyItems': {
                'itemCount': nb_art_pass_caiss,
                'itemCountProg': nb_art_pass_caiss_prog
            },
            'dailyBasket': {
                'average': basket,
                'averageProg': prog_basket
            },
            'dailyDiscount': remise,
            'dailyMargin': {
                'currentYear': marginN,
                'previousYear': marginN1
            }
        }
    }
}
return Response(response)
```

I am looking for ways to iterate through a range/list of store numbers and get a response with a section for each one.

Comment: The example doesn't make sense. There is pure SQL (why not use something like SQLAlchemy), Pandas code and some JSON response. This is not an example anyone will understand.

Comment: I am querying against a VectorWise database so I have to write it that way to be able to translate with my environment variables! I am just a noob at API development, I am more of a data engineer.